# Should I let my pets eat corpses?

Tags: nethack

After I acquire the particular intrinsic conveyed by a corpse, I most often let my pets eat the rest (unless I need food).  I've looked on the wiki, but haven't found anything about whether this allows the pet to also acquire that intrinsic.  It would be nice to know if my large cat/dog/warhorse is or isn't fireproof before entering Gehennom.  This question extends to Giants for strength, and any other corpse-borne benefits as well.

Do pets (particularly, horses,dogs, and cats) gain intrinsics and/or or other benefits from eating corpses?

Comment: Not as far as I know, they can't get intrinsics. I always let them eat most of the corpses though, because I can find other food.

Comment: Based on my experience with real life pets, if they want to eat something dead, you're not going to be able to stop them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, let the pets eat!

Pets gain tameness eating. The only time you might not want them to eat (other than the obvious you want the intrinsic) a corpse is when there are other enemies around however I think they'll attack first and eat later.

Sometimes you might want to get rid of a corpse - a troll for example, pets are ideal for this!.

However, pets cannot get intrinsic's by eating - however some are born with them (such as dragons).

Comment: -1, "Pets gain size and stats by eating." is incorrect. The only stat affected by eating corspes is tameness. Size isn't affected one bit by eating, nor do they gain any other stats from eating.

Comment: Oh yeah now I remember, it's just the tameness. It's fighting for size.

Comment: That's all wiki info, and just to clarify:

Comment: That's all wiki info, and just to clarify, pets gain HP by fighting and winning (let them finish, unless in danger of dying), and they level up to suit HP. Tameness is upped by not being hungry.  I wanted to know if pets can gain intrinsics, as players can, by eating specific corpses.  Apparently, they don't.  Now, I'm wondering about rings and intelligent monsterts with hands.